# AWS Redshift delete from and truncate commands hang in process

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to both understand and resolve what I believe to be a problem with commands hanging indefinitely.

I am taking bucket objects from S3 and manipulating said objects, so they can be inserted into Redshift table. During the manipulation of the S3 objects I ran into an issue. To start over and study this problem, I was going to flush the data base with a `delete from table` command programmatically from the application via `psql`. One of the tables were deleted, but two of the tables didn't delete (sessions:76,000 rows // generated: 4,600 rows). I then tried using truncate, but I was still unable to do anything. I knew something was strange at this point.

I stopped testing the application, and I went to the Redshift console in AWS, it didn't even recognize that a `delete from table` or `truncate table` command had been terminated after hanging. I then looked at the following tables with:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
SELECT * FROM stv_inflight
```

For stv_inflight I only showed one query running

```
dev=> SELECT * FROM stv_inflight;
 userid | slice |  query   |             label              |   xid    | pid  |         starttime          |                                                 text                                                 | suspended | insert_pristine 
--------+-------+----------+--------------------------------+----------+------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------
    101 |  6411 | 40649860 | default                        | 26156672 | 4529 | 2015-08-19 22:23:55.795223 | SELECT * FROM stv_inflight;                                                                          |         0 |               0
(1 row)
```

For pg_stat_activity I received this monstrosity.

```
dev=> SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
 datid  | datname | procpid | usesysid | usename |        current_query         | query_start 
--------+---------+---------+----------+---------+------------------------------+-------------
 100058 | dev     |    1200 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2761 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2762 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2763 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2769 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2767 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2770 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2764 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2768 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2766 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2765 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2862 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2863 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2864 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2865 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2866 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2870 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2869 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2867 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2868 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |   22407 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2871 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    2907 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    3995 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    3997 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    3996 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    3998 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    3999 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4000 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4001 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4002 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4003 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4004 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4029 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4030 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4031 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4033 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4032 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4035 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4034 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4036 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4037 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4038 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4071 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4075 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4074 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4072 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4073 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4077 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4076 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4078 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4080 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4079 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4254 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4255 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4256 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4257 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4260 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4261 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4259 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4263 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4258 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4262 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4297 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4300 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4299 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4298 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4301 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4303 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4302 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4305 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4304 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4306 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4307 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4308 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4309 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4311 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4310 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4313 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4312 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4315 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4316 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4314 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4416 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4417 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4418 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4420 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4421 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4423 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4422 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4424 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4419 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4425 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    4529 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    5005 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    5006 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    5014 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    5015 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    5169 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    5171 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    5396 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    5397 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    5399 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    5398 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    5465 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |    5466 |      101 | dev     | <command string not enabled> | 
 100058 | dev     |   20090 |        1 | rdsdb   | <insufficient privilege>     | 
 100058 | dev     |   20094 |        1 | rdsdb   | <insufficient privilege>     | 
 100058 | dev     |   20518 |        1 | rdsdb   | <insufficient privilege>     | 
 100058 | dev     |    6602 |        1 | rdsdb   | <insufficient privilege>     | 
 100058 | dev     |    8126 |        1 | rdsdb   | <insufficient privilege>     | 
(111 rows)
```

What would be the cause of this and what would be a work around?

edit: I know that dropping my sessions table and generated table will remove all of these processes, but I would prefer to not drop production tables, ever.